# Getting from Bangladesh to Malaysia with current restrictions

Tags: covid-19, uk-citizens, malaysia, bangladesh

I'm a UK citizen, two-shot vaccinated against COVID-19, now in Chattogram, Bangladesh. I really want to leave Bangladesh and return to my family in Malaysia.  I just can't figure my way through the restrictions on travel, and with the situation in India, not too many places (or airlines) want to take anyone from Bangladesh. I figured maybe I could try and get to the UK and then go back to Malaysia from there but I can't even work out if I'd need to quarantine in the UK first, either for UK rules or Malaysian. How best to solve my problem?

Comment: The part of your question related to getting back to the UK is relatively easy to answer. Bangladesh is on the ‘red list’ so although as a UK citizen you are allowed to travel to the UK, travelling there direct would still require proof of a negative PCR test and you would have to complete mandatory 10 day quarantine in a government-approved hotel https://www.gov.uk/guidance/transport-measures-to-protect-the-uk-from-variant-strains-of-covid-19 Being two-shot vaccinated currently makes no difference to the restrictions. See also https://www.gov.uk/foreign-travel-advice/malaysia

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the pandemic is now over.

Comment: I can understand the question being closed; my problem was solved long ago. But "the pandemic is now over" !?? Seriously??  Better tell the W.H.O.